# Express cookie checking throws TypeError

Tags: javascript, express, cookies

I've made a function such as:
`const token = req.cookies['SESSION_DATA']  if (token) { ... } catch (err) { ... }`
However, on checking for a token, i get a TypeError "Cannot read property of undefined".
The exact same function works on my other project which doesn't throw TypeError when there is not cookie 'SESSION_DATA'. I tried setting `const token = undefined`, it would never pass the if. If i try to check for cookies `req.cookies['SESSION_DATA']`, i'm getting TypeError, even if its in a if statement.

Comment: must mean `req` or `req.cookies` is undefined, since `undefined` has no properties, it will throw that error - check if either of those are undefined, and fix that problem in your code

Comment: It seems when u copy the architecture of your last project, you can miss crucial things. However, req.cookies in my other project is an empty object but the exact same code shows that req.cookies is undefined. And that is the only place that read and use cookies. Maybe something with cookie-parser.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the cookie-parser im using is set before my middlewares so it is undefined. Moving the priority fixed this.